# Edit WPF Toolkit to get the DatePicker only

Tags: wpf, datepicker, wpftoolkit

I am doing a small application and i need a DatePicker control, So i use the WPF toolkit datepicker. After completing my application I notice that my application exe has of size 250k and the WPFToolkit dll has a size 442k. So i am extracting the datepicker control from the toolkit by deleting the other controls from it. But it is not working for me. The application is failed when running. How can I extract the datepicker control only from the toolkit?

Comment: Could you provide more detail? Is there a compilation error, or does your customized version of the library fail at runtime?

Comment: Yes My customized version of the library fail at runtime.

Comment: Post the exception and the stacktrace I guess. You might have removed a dependency by accident.

Comment: Also, are you sure that this is a big concern for you? Honestly, the performance improvements will be negligible(stuff you don't use won't be loaded), and an extra 400k doesn't seem like a such a big deal. On the other hand - cutting down a library by hand means hassle down the road when new versions of the library come out and you'd like to update. This sounds like a classic case of premature optimization to me, you shouldn't be bothering with this until everything works great and is tested, and even then only if it poses a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the source code for the WPF Toolkit from Codeplex. Copy the files you need into your project and eliminate the dependency. When adding the file(s) you will find out what else you need to get your project compiling. They probably use some base classes that you eliminated.